# onAppear for views created in a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewcontroller, iboutlet

I am using a library, which is more tailored towards Swift UI, but I am creating app based on regular Views and ViewControllers.
The object for that library need to be declared(at least from my understanding) it as either @StateObject or @ObservableObject, I get the same error for both:

***Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.***

From similar issues, the solution seems to be to use .onAppear([Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time - SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930434/accessing-stateobjects-object-without-being-installed-on-a-view-this-will-crea)), but I am lost on how to call .onAppear for an @IBOutlet
Is there a way to call .onAppear for a view, which is declared as:

@IBOutlet var hostView: CPTGraphHostingView!

?

**UPDATE**

If I declare the object as

var conductor = TunerConductor()

The Tuner Conductor errors out with the same throw in the initialization phase:

```
  init() {
    print("init started ")
    guard let input = engine.input else { fatalError() }

    guard let device = engine.inputDevice else { fatalError() }
    print("input selected")
    initialDevice = device

    mic = input
    tappableNodeA = Fader(mic)
    tappableNodeB = Fader(tappableNodeA)
    tappableNodeC = Fader(tappableNodeB)
    silence = Fader(tappableNodeC, gain: 0)
    engine.output = silence
    print("objects init")
    tracker = PitchTap(mic) { pitch, amp in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.update(pitch[0], amp[0])
        }
    }
    
}
```

Output looks like:

> init started
>
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.604952-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606254-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606352-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606437-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606514-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606606-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606685-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606764-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.606839-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
>
> input selected
>
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.615502-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.615950-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.616028-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.616097-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.616167-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.616237-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.616320-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.616396-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
> 2022-04-22 17:53:21.616471-0700 SING[9300:646252] throwing -10878
>
> objects init

There are no mentions of this error code in the library nor in swift in general, so I am lost what can it be.

Comment: UIKit has a completely different lifecycle to SwiftUI views (which are structs and therefore recreated each time their content changes). You don't need `@StateObject` to keep the object around. You can just create the object in `viewDidLoad` and store the reference in a property

Comment: So just var conductor = TunerConductor()? Because when I try to do it this way it says: throwing -10878 a bunch of times, without any more comments, when I run it

Comment: Please look at the updated post

Comment: What is the context of the code you have shown? Is it in a view controller subclass? Some other class? The error you are getting is `kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter`

Comment: I have a VC. I copied over the TunerConductor() inside of the VC class, so that the app at least boosts. In my viewDidLoad, I do the same calls which are inside of init(). This made the app run, however, the error still gets printed.